# LVM mounted ubuntu 12.04. No space left on device

Tags: 12.04, mount, lvm, disk-usage

I have a logical volume that is 2.44 TB in size which is mounted. I use it to store movies and TV shows for sharing on the home network. However, all of a sudden the system now gives the error: No space left on device, when trying to copy more data over. Obviously, I checked using df -h and -i and both show free space and free nodes!

```
Filesystem                          Inodes  IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/Server-MediaBox      163840000  15170 163824830    1% /media/MediaBox

Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/Server-MediaBox       2.5T  1.2T  1.2T  50% /media/MediaBox
```

I don't understand where this error is arising from? Please offer advice as I have looked everywhere online and can't seem to find a similar problem. Thank you :)

Comment: Did you use lvextend to grow the volume without resizing the filesystem (resize2fs)?

Comment: I didn't extend my logical volume in first place but just in case I tried the resize2fs. It just said that the filesytem was already 655360000 blocks long. Nothing to do! So I assume this means the partition is fully taking up the drive space.